# What is the name for an integer partition with bounded multiplicities?

Tags: co.combinatorics, terminology, partitions

Is there a standard name for integer partitions $\lambda \in (\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0})^n$, $\lambda_i \geq \lambda_{i+1}$, with multiplicities at most $k$, i.e. $\lambda_i > \lambda_{i+k}$ for all $i$?

(If $k=1$ then $\lambda$ is called *strict*. One might call these '$k$-strict partitions', but I prefer not to make up terminology.)

Next, note that the conjugate partition $\mu := \lambda'$ has consecutive differences $\mu_i - \mu_{i+1} \leq k$. Does that property for $\mu$ have a standard name?

Comment: Integer partitions with multiplicities at most $k$ is a bit long, but clear, and I do not see how to do better.

Comment: I have found a paper [Partitions with a Restriction on the Multiplicity of the Summands](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1995692) by Hagis, and another one [Asymptotic formulas for partitions with bounded multiplicity](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/applied-algebra-and-number-theory/asymptotic-formulas-for-partitions-with-bounded-multiplicity/5CBB39D3021CF82B9C16007952B9CE90) by Liardet and Thomas.

Comment: (Just for the record: neither paper mentioned by @BillyJoe give the property a name)

Comment: In the representation theory literature, the term "$p$-regular" means that $\lambda$ does not contain $p$ parts of the same size (i.e. "$(p-1)$-strict" in the terminology you suggest). This is an essential concept in the modular representation theory of symmetric groups: see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specht_module . However, a quick search indicates that some combinatorialists use the term "$p$-regular" to instead mean there are no positive parts that are multiples of $p$.

Comment: @ChristopherRyba Thanks! Some more searching suggests the overlap in terminology is no coincidence: a theorem of Glaisher ("A theorem in partitions", 1883) states that the two types of $p$-regular partitions are in bijection at fixed weight $|\lambda| = \sum_i \lambda_i$. See e.g. the introduction of Konan's paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.12366 . Moreover, in the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.00300, Konan uses the termionology $k+1$-*flat* for the property I described for the conjugate partition $\mu$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is also the notion of a $p$-regular conjugacy class, which is a conjugacy class such that any element has order coprime to $p$. These index the rows of the table of Brauer characters (the "mod $p$" version of the character table), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_representation_theory . The combinatorialists' version of $p$-regular partition is the cycle type of such a conjugacy class in $S_n$ (warning: $p$-regular cycle type is only equivalent to having order coprime to $p$ when $p$ is a prime number; (12)(345) has order 6 but no parts divisible by 6).

Answer (score 1):

For the second question concerning partitions with bounded differences between consecutive parts, William Keith's 2007 thesis (advisor George Andrews) may be the first use of the term $m$-flat.  He mentions that flat is used in the description of [OEIS A034296](https://oeis.org/A034296).  That "base case" notion has also been called gap-free (Grabner--Prodinger 2006) and compact (Andrews 2016).

For the first question, I do not know of a succinct name that's been used.  People are still coining names for generalized partition statistics (e.g., I made up the term $k$-step partitions for a 2020 paper), so maybe you should coin some new terminology---it might gain some traction.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean $k+1$-flat?

Comment: @JulesLamers Probably!  I didn't compare the definitions and just used his variable choice.  His thesis is at https://www.math.drexel.edu/~keith/Thesis.pdf and the relevant definition is on p33.

Comment: @JulesLamers I edited to remove the conflicting variables.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, I called them "Andrews class partitions" in [Limit Shapes via Bijections](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.06073).[image]

For the second question, the *complement* condition $\mu_i - \mu_{i+1} \geq d$ is usually called "Minimal Difference $d$ Partitions".[image]

Comment: Thanks! May I infer that, before your paper, the name 'Andrews class partitions' was not used, and you do not know of other names? And that the name 'minimal difference-$d$ partitions' is more standard?

Comment: NB. For easy reference: the cited paper is from 2016 (arXiv preprint) and was published in 2019.

Comment: If I recall correctly, yes to the first question.  For the second I got it from Dan Romik's manuscript.  I would ask him if he coined it since he put it in quotes.